# Paperclip image.url in Backbone.js Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, paperclip

I am using paperclip to save images.  Everything works fine and I am able to access the item's url with @item.image.url.

```
class Item
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
      :original => ['1920x1680>', :jpg],
      :small => ['100x100>', :jpg],
      :medium => ['250x250>', :jpg],
      :large => ['500x500>', :jpg]
    }
end
```

This is console:

```
> Item.last.image.url(:small)
=> "/system/images/items/1/small/chanel.jpg?1334005208"
```

This is straightforward and easy if I am templating HAML or ERB from the server and serving up the page to the user like this. items/show.html.haml:

```
.item
  .item-image
    = image_tag @item.image.url(:small)
```

However, with backbone.js, I am unable to construct the URL because I do not have the paperclip helpers in context.  Essentially, I am sending the following attributes of the image to the page in json form.

```
#<Item:0x007fc97559b960> {
                    :id => 1,
    :image_content_type => "image/jpeg",
       :image_file_name => "chanel.jpg",
       :image_file_size => 28880,
      :image_updated_at => 2012-04-09 21:00:08 UTC
}
```

What is a ninja way to get the image.url included as an attribute on the item.  How do I account for the style URLS?  It would be nice to have an attribute like "image_small_url", "image_normal_url", etc predetermined and accessible.  Thoughts?

Comment: how are sending the attributes of the image to the page in json form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using [Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to build the JSON views for a project I'm working on, so my `index` view, for example looks like this:

```
json.array!(@things) do |json, thing|
  json.id thing.id
  json.name thing.name
  json.description thing.description
  json.image_url thing.image.url
  json.thumb_url thing.image.url(:thumb)
end
```

That way in my Backbone template, I can just say `thing.get('image_url')` and `thing.get('thumb_url')`.

In brief, you'll want to use something like Jbuilder, or manually override `as_json` in your model. Personally, I like taking care of this at the view level, which is what Jbuilder allows you to do easily.

Comment: Thanks! extremely helpful. Model.to_json is a good spot to filter out sensitive attributes like :encoded_password, too.  Brilliant.

Comment: Also note that overriding `Model.as_json` is generally recommended over `Model.to_json`, as `as_json` is used by `to_json` to actually create the desired data structure.

Comment: how do i get image_url in show.jst.ejs file. show_view.js.coffee is retuning  @$el.html(@template(@model.toJSON() )) and in show.jst.ejs file I show the details as <%= title %> ..... How to show photo_url in show page

Answer (score 1):

While generating JSON in controllers is  doable, I *greatly* prefer wrapping up this kind of functionality in either decorators (e.g., [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)), or into frameworks designed for RESTful resources (e.g., [Roar](https://github.com/apotonick/roar)).

This keeps the mapping between models and their external representations highly localized, allows direct testing of representations outside of the web app framework, and so on.

For example, clem's answer would be isolated within a single class, roughly:

```
class ThingDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def image_url; object.image.url;         end
  def thumb_url; object.image.url(:thumb); end
end
```

Then in the controller, for example:

```
@things = Thing.some_scope.decorate # Or
@things = ThingDecorator.decorate_collection(Thing.all)
```

(Or whatever you need, and what works depends on the Rails version, see the Draper docs.)

Then expose the collection as JSON using normal means. IMO this is almost always cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple example using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder):

```
# index.json.jbuilder
json.array!(@shared_snap_casts) do |shared_snap_cast|
  json.extract! shared_snap_cast, :id, :snap
end
```

Here the `:snap` is the paperclip attachment - the output from this example is:

```
[{"id":1,"snap":"/system/shared_snap_casts/snaps/000/000/001/original/some_icon.png?1388093936"}]
```

Hope this helps!